# Short story about ice racing on glaciers or gletschers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

[it's solved: Mirror of Ice by Gary Wright]
Years ago, I read a short story in an anthology, (a collection of SF-shorts), which was about **ice-racing**. A dozen pilots went down a glacier/**gletscher** mountain, in, I assume, bobsled-like vehicles. They were dare devils, committed to racing, but since this was fairly dangerous, also all kind of crazy. It was probably the authors idea to do a **Formula 1-on-ice,** but even more spectacular.

*(beware, spoilers)*

I can remember two lines:
*"They only found the body of XXXX the following Spring, when the ice had melted"*
and a fictional interview with the winner of the race:
Q: *"When did you feel you started to lose control?"*
A: *"At the starting line"*

The anthology maker could be Gardner Dozois, or Geoffrey/Geoff something or someone else entirely.

Era: definitely before the 80s (1940-1980), but most likely before the seventies, so 1950-1970

Question: what was its name and author?

Comment: Having reread the story, I didn't realize that the story is open-ended! Actually, the story doesn't really stop after the race, he merely describes in his mind **what** happens after a race. But not this one,.....

Comment: Your question has been closed as a Duplicate. Please note that that does not mean it is a bad question, just that it's been asked before, and we like to set up database links to help find them in the future. Also, we don't really do questions in the main site, so I'm removing that added bit. With a little more rep, you'll be able to join the chat room where we do discuss such things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ***[Mirror of Ice](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52389)*** by Gary Wright, first published in [the June 1967 issue](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58560) of *Galaxy Magazine*.

Some relevant extracts:

> But others had not been so lucky.
>
> **Hans Kroger: they finally dug his body out of eighteen feet
> of snow;** he'd gone -all the way to the dirt. His sled had been
> airborne -when he blew and upside-down!
>
> Jarl Yorgensen: his sled tumbling and he ejected directly
> under the following sleds. No one was certain that all of him
> was ever found)
>
> Max Conrad: a perfect blowout! At least 350 feet up and
> slightly downhill . . . His chute never opened.

> The hospital. How many times had he awakened here?
> And it was always wonderfully the same: gentle warmth and
> his body finally relaxed and he would test it piece by piece to
> see what was bent and broken this time; and always the
> newsmen and the writers and the other assorted ghouls, and
> always the question and answer period. Punchlining, they
> called it. . . .
>
> "How did it happen?"
>
> "I dozed off."
>
> "Why didn't you eject?"
>
> "Parachuting is dangerous."
>
> **"When did you realize you were out of control?"**
>
> **"At the starting line."**
>
> "What will you do now?"
>
> "Heal."
>
> "Will you race again?"
>
> . . . "It's possible."

You can read the full story [here](https://groups.google.com/g/rec.arts.sf.written/c/tF2gWUrE_fY).

Comment: Thanks. It seems the anthology was by Harry Harrison. That kind of feels right, as in, he seems of the same era, but I don't really remember it like that.